# Erlang B formula to solve a probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, markov-process, queueing-theory

I am trying to solve this problem where I need to express a probability problem as a queueing problem. I'm having troubles getting the distributions right.

Here's the problem:

There are $n$ keys, only one of them opens the lock. Find the average number of keys tried before the door is opened.

As a probability problem,I solve it like this. Let $\xi$ be the r.v. for number of attempts. Then my goal is to calculate $\mathbb{E}\xi$. Then $k-th$ attempt is successful if attempts $1,\dots,k-1$ failed and $k-th$ succeeded. Then
$$\mathbb{E}\xi=1\cdot\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=2}^n\Big(k\frac{1}{n-k+1}\prod_{m=0}^{k-2}\frac{n-m-1}{n-m}\Big)$$
i.e. for $n=3$, for example:
$$\mathbb{E}\xi=1\cdot\frac{1}{3}+2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+3\cdot1\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=2$$

I'm quite sure that $\mathbb{E}\xi=\frac{\sum_{m=1}^nm}{n}\quad\forall n\geq 1$ because every key is equally likely to open the lock. So, we are equally likely to have the correct key on any attempt.

My goal is to solve this problem using the Erlang B formula:
$$E_k=\frac{\alpha^k/k!}{\sum_{m=0}^k\alpha^m/m!}$$
where $\alpha=\lambda/\beta$ is traffic, $k$ - number of used resources (channels).

I need to describe this probability problem as a queuing problem to obtain a solution with Erlang B. If I assume that the average number of attempts is the average number of channels used to obtain the right key, I have the following distribution of $\xi$:

| $\xi$ | 1 | 2 | ... | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prob. of right key | 1-$E_1$ | $E_2-E_1$ | ... | $E_n-E_{n-1}$ |

the expected value is then
$$\mathbb{E}\xi=\sum_{k=1}^nk(E_{k-1}-E_k)\quad\text{where }E_0=1$$

I apply this formula to $n=3$ (3 keys mean 3 total possibilities, thus 3 channels) and $\alpha=1$ (1 key per try) and get $\mathbb{E}\xi\sim 1.512<2$. I then try to recalculate for different $n,\alpha$ and never get the correct answer.

How do I interpret/assign the parameters in Erlang B to get on the right track?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Do you keep track of the keys you have tested or not?

Comment: To be clear: if you do not keep track of the tested keys, so each trial succeeds independently of the others with probability $\frac 1n$, this is a standard Geometric Distribution.  If you do keep track, then the distribution is uniform (as the  key is equally likely to be any of the $n$).  In neither case is there a need for extensive computation.

Comment: @lulu I myself am not sure whether keys are kept. My goal isn't just any solution, I have to solve using Erlang B formula. Erlang B here describes consecutive calls, $E_k$ is the probability of loss over channels $1,\dots,k$. So, I think we keep track of the keys.